# TensorFlow: LSTM State Saving/Updating within Graph

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am working with Reinforcement Learning and wanting to reduce the amount of data I feed through the sess.run() during training to speed up learning.

I was looking into the LSTM and with the need to look forward and reset to find proper Q values, I crafted a solution such as this with tf.case():

> ```
>     CurrentStateOption = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='SavedState')
> ```

```
    with tf.name_scope("LSTMLayer") as scope:
        initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-.1, .1)
        lstm_cell_L1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.input_sizes, forget_bias=1.0, initializer=initializer, state_is_tuple=True)
        self.cell_L1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_L1] *self.NumberLSTMLayers, state_is_tuple=True)
        self.state = self.cell_L1.zero_state(1,tf.float64)

        self.SavedState = self.cell_L1.zero_state(1,tf.float64)   #tf.Variable(state, trainable=False, name='SavedState')

        #SaveCond    = tf.cond(tf.equal(CurrentStateOption,tf.constant(1)), self.SaveState, self.SameState)
        #RestoreCond = tf.cond(tf.equal(CurrentStateOption,tf.constant(-1)), self.RestoreState, self.SameState)
        #ZeroCond    = tf.cond(tf.less(CurrentStateOption,tf.constant(-1)), self.ZeroState, self.SameState)

        self.state = tf.case({tf.equal(CurrentStateOption,tf.constant(1)): self.SaveState, tf.equal(CurrentStateOption,tf.constant(-1)): self.RestoreState,
            tf.less(CurrentStateOption,tf.constant(-1)): self.ZeroState}, default=self.SameState, exclusive=True)

        RunConditions = tf.group([SaveCond, RestoreCond, ZeroCond])

        self.Xinputs = [tf.concat(1,[Xinputs])]

        outputs, stateFINAL_L1 = rnn.rnn(self.cell_L1,self.Xinputs, initial_state=self.state, dtype=tf.float32)
```

> ```
> def RestoreState(self):
>     #self.state = self.state.assign(self.SavedState)
>     self.state = self.SavedState
>     return self.state
> def ZeroState(self):
>     self.state = self.cell_L1.zero_state(1,tf.float64)
>     return self.state
> def SaveState(self):
>     #self.SavedState = self.SavedState.assign(self.state)
>     self.SavedState = self.state
>     return  self.SavedState
> def SameState(self):
>     return self.state
> ```

This seems to work well in concept as now I can feed an INT to instruct the LSTM Graph what to do with the state.  If I Pass "1" it will save the state before executing, if I pass "-1" it will Restore the last saved state, if I pass "< -1" it will zero the state.  If "0" it will use what is in the LSTM from last run (inference).  I have tried a few different approaches, include a simpler tf.cond() approach.

The issue I think stems from the tf.case() Op needing tensors, but the LSTM state is a Tuple (and non-tuple is going to be depreciated).  This became clear when I tried to tf.assign() the value to the graph variable.

My end goal is to leave the "state" within the graph, but pass an INT to instruct what to do with the state.  In the future I would like to have multiple "store" locations for various look-backs.

Any ideas how to handle tf.case() type of structure with tuples vs tensors?

Answer (score 0):

I believe having one tf.case() per element in the state tuple should work, since the tuple is just a python tuple.